# How to get first in and last out and convert to another format

Tags: sql-server, date, time

Thanks in advance for your help.

Hi there, i have a table AttendDB as show below it has many confused data.

```
Name    Date    Time    Status
4900651 14/12/2015  7:52    I
4900651 14/12/2015  12:26   O
4900651 14/12/2015  12:27   I
4900651 14/12/2015  17:04   O
4900651 15/12/2015  7:51    I
4900651 15/12/2015  12:04   O
4900651 15/12/2015  12:08   I
4900651 15/12/2015  17:03   O
4900651 16/12/2015  7:50    I
4900651 16/12/2015  12:12   O
4900651 16/12/2015  12:13   I
4900651 16/12/2015  17:03   O
4900651 17/12/2015  7:52    I
4900651 17/12/2015  12:09   O
4900651 17/12/2015  12:35   I
4900651 17/12/2015  17:02   O
4900651 18/12/2015  7:54    I
4900651 18/12/2015  12:16   O
4900651 18/12/2015  12:17   I
4900651 18/12/2015  17:04   O
4900651 21/12/2015  7:48    I
4900651 22/12/2015  7:49    I
4900651 22/12/2015  12:11   O
4900651 22/12/2015  12:31   I
4900651 23/12/2015  7:46    I
4900651 23/12/2015  12:13   O
4900651 23/12/2015  12:13   I
4900651 23/12/2015  17:05   O
4900651 24/12/2015  7:49    I
4900651 24/12/2015  12:22   O
4900651 24/12/2015  12:23   I
4900651 24/12/2015  17:04   O
4900651 25/12/2015  7:54    I
4900651 25/12/2015  12:27   i
4900651 25/12/2015  12:28   O
4900651 25/12/2015  12:28   I
4900651 25/12/2015  17:04   O
4900651 26/12/2015  7:46    I
4900652 9/12/2015   11:28   I
4900652 11/12/2015  8:55    I
4900652 12/12/2015  16:10   I
4900652 12/12/2015  16:10   I
4900652 12/12/2015  16:10   I
4900652 12/12/2015  16:11   I
4900652 12/12/2015  16:12   I
4900652 12/12/2015  17:01   O
```

in data have many data per name entry because my HR want to keep six time per work day of employee "in-out(lunch) in(after lunch)-out(work) in(ot)-out(ot) I want the output as first in and last out show below

```
Name    Date    Time    Status
4900651 14/12/2015  7:52    I
4900651 14/12/2015  17:04   O
4900651 15/12/2015  7:51    I
4900651 15/12/2015  17:03   O
4900651 16/12/2015  7:50    I
4900651 16/12/2015  17:03   O
4900651 17/12/2015  7:52    I
4900651 17/12/2015  17:02   O
4900652 14/12/2015  7:58    I
4900652 15/12/2015  17:04   O
```

and if i want to query file to format like below, it can be do it?
Thank for many help

```
4900651,14122015,0752I
4900651,14122015,1704O
4900651,15122015,0751I
4900651,15122015,1703O
4900651,16122015,0750I
4900651,16122015,1703O
4900651,17122015,0752I
4900651,17122015,1702O
4900652,14122015,0758I
4900652,15122015,1704O
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi use below query to get your required results

```
SELECT NAME,
       DATE,
       CASE WHEN STATUS='I' THEN MIN(TIME)
       ELSE
       MAX(TIME)
       END
       TIME,
       STATUS 
FROM AttendDB GROUP BY NAME,DATE,STATUS
```

And for generating file you can use below code

```
SELECT convert(varchar(20),NAME)+','+
       convert(varchar(20),DATE)+','+
       CASE WHEN STATUS='I' THEN convert(varchar(20),MIN(TIME))
       ELSE
       convert(varchar(20),MAX(TIME))
       END +status output
FROM   AttendDB GROUP BY NAME,DATE,STATUS
```

For Returning above query results into a file you have to follow the below steps

1. Save the above query in .sql file.
2. Open cmd and type `sqlcmd -U user_name -S server_name -i input file(.sql) -o (Output file path) C:\users\query.txt(example)`
3. Enter Your Password.

Note:- Input file contains the query.

After all above steps results returned by the query will copied to query.txt file. It doesn't mean we have to use only .txt we can use .csv etc also.

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  This rewards @Tarun and helps other people with the same issue to find the answer.  If it didn't help please add a comment explaining why.

Comment: Thanks for your helps @Tarun. but have a bit questions if i want to query by specify date or name can add to code ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can specify date or name to query with the use of where clause.